# external hard drive permission error

Tags: permissions, external-hdd

I have an HP notebook with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and a Toshiba 1TB external hard drive.

My laptop powered off unintentionally, and when I turned it back on I was no longer the "owner" of my external hard drive.  This meant my bittorrent could not access those files, despite being admin.  I can change each file's permissions but it does not stick and when I do it for the hard drive itself I do not have permission.  From all the forums and wiki's I've looked through it seems I have an identity problem.  The power outage affected how my computer sees the external hard drive or how the hard drive sees the computer.  I'm not sure how to change it so the files stay relevant.

Output from `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=787f0ef1-1d02-44d5-9604-00d2c8126fdc / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2cf7cde6-cb14-4a0b-95b8-63e9d804ddda none swap sw 0 0
```

Output from `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
command not found
```

Output from `mount`:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=chad)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/chad/Chad1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `mount` and `sudo fdisk -l` while the hard drive is connected?

Comment: chad@chad-HP-Mini-110-1000:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=787f0ef1-1d02-44d5-9604-00d2c8126fdc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

Comment: # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2cf7cde6-cb14-4a0b-95b8-63e9d804ddda none            swap    sw              0       0
this is the out come of cat /etc/fstab

Comment: command fdisk-1 said command not found

Comment: chad@chad-HP-Mini-110-1000:~$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)

Comment: none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=chad)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/chad/Chad1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
this is outcome for mount

Comment: @ChadG.Holmgren: Please [edit] your question if you want to add additional info instead of putting it in the comments, especially if it consists of multiple lines of (pre-formatted) program output.

Comment: Can you make certain you entered the command `sudo fdisk -l` correctly? You can paste into a terminal with `Ctrl+Shift+V` to make sure. If the command still isn't found you can install it with `sudo apt-get install util-linux`. Based on `mount` I'm assuming your external is formatted `ext4` and called `Chad1`; is that correct? If so, it is mounted `rw` and not `ro` so that's not the problem. Can you also post (edit your question) the output of `ls -l /media/chad`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might have permission errors:

To solve it you need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo chmod u+rw,g+rw /media/USERNAME/DRIVENAME
```

*This quite possibly isn't the problem*

Answer (score 0):

Other suggestion would be using the GUI. Open your terminal and type

gksudo nautilus

Nautilus will open in root mode, don't close the terminal at this point!

In Nautilus find your HDD, click on Properties and to to Permissions tab.
Check if all permissions adress your username and your group, then check the "ChangePermissions for Enclosed Files" option. That should solve your problems without extended use of terminal ;) [image]